# Retrieve API keys in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I've recently started using Firebase to host my projects, Say I've scheduled a job every 5 minutes that makes an API call to a third party, normally I would store the credentials for this 3rd party in a .env file on the server but I don't think I can do this with Firebase? So how do you go about retrieving third party keys on Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about Cloud Functions, then you'd accomplish this by [using environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env). From that documentation, you can **set** environment variables from your developer or CI/CD system with:

```
firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"
```

And then access it from within your Cloud Functions code with:

```
functions.config().someservice.id
```

See the linked documentation for full details.